# How to overwrite NA in a dataframe by using is.na or is.infinite in the Adjusted Fold Change Code?

Tags: r, na, overwrite

I am creating a plot in r and have to replace the NA values with a small number like 1e-10. I need to overwrite the NA (or Infinite Value, which is what you get if you try to make R do math with NA) in the Adjusted fold change code, by using is.na() or is.infinite().

The data frame name is WVLyme.
I tried the following code:

`ADJ<-which(WVLyme,is.na(1e-10))`

then I tried:

`WVLyme[is.na(WVLyme)] <- 1^-10`

but when I tried to do the fold change code after:

`with(WVLyme,max(RawFChange)`

nothing came up and I got an error.

```
{r}
WVLyme[is.na(WVLyme)] <- 1^-10
with(WVLyme,max(RawFChange)
```

`Error: unexpected ',' in "WVLyme[is.na(WVLyme)] <- 1^-10,"`

Comment: Several easily fixed typos/errors: The error message `Error: unexpected ',' in "WVLyme[is.na(WVLyme)] <- 1^-10,"` makes it appear you have a stray comma. `1e-10` and `1^-10` are not the same thing. You're missing a closing `)` at the end of your `with` call. It's really helpful if you check for typos before posting. Also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making a reproducible question

Comment: I apologize for the errors, I know what the error messages mean and I know I was missing an end parenthesis,, but the code was not working even when fixing those issues. The code was not the correct code overall. I was out a week in class and I'm just trying to understand the assignment. Thanks...

Comment: Okay, but why post code that you know has typos, rather than fixing the typos before posting? That just adds to the work of folks you're asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base R you can replace your `NA` with another value like this:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- Inf

    a   b
1 Inf Inf
2   1   1
3   2   2
```

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(NA, 1, 2), 
           b = c(NA, 1, 2))
```